# How do I keep a full view box image float on the left half and text scroll on the right half of the page

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-5

Someone with no coding experience is trying HTML. I feel really stupid to ask this question, but I am stuck on this for two weeks.

A picture says more than a thousand words. I made a page in a web builder, but I want to replicate it in HTML (with bootstrap 5). I want an image fullscreen left half and text right half of the screen.

Now I tried it in HTML. I used 2 col-md columns in a row that will stack when the device width gets below 768px. The first column has a full height and full width (50% when device wider than 768px) image as background. Second column has text. I want the image to stay full height, no scroll on the left side of page. I used this code:

```
<body>    
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md plaatje vh-100"> </div>
        <div class="col-md text-center px-5 py-5">
        <h1>
        <b>NAME</b>
        </h1>
        <p class="text-secondary">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis volutpat.
        </p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<style>
.plaatje {
background: url("https://www.vitality-club.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/IMG_9218.jpeg") no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</body>
```

The problem is that when the viewport in the browser is smaller than the text on the right side I can scroll the image and see white bars above and below the image. Please help me get it fixed. (I used a background image, but maybe that is not the best way. Feel free to change that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't really understand your question 100%, but made a Code Snippet with HTML and CSS from what i understand. In my CSS i used vw (view width to make it responsive) and for the padding "rem" (font size) instead of px to make it responsive.

-Noel

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  right: 50vw;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://www.vitality-club.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/IMG_9218.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0 2.5rem 0 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
  <h1>NAME</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Noel. I got it to work as I want thanks to a friend and your code. If I add

`@media (max-width: 768px) {
.left {
position: relative;
}
.right {
width: 100vw;
}
}`

Then it will stack when the viewport is less than 768px! Thank you.